# wpf c# can't open window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've created a new window in wpf named AfterLogin.
I'm trying to open it with button like

```
VMR_Launcher.AfterLogin af = new VMR_Launcher.AfterLogin();
af.Show();
```

and like that

```
AfterLogin af = new AfterLogin();
af.Show();
```

It throws error `Cannot locate resource AfterLogin.xaml`

I have other windows too, but they working with those commands, and this afterlogin not. idk why.
Every new window doesn't work too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF IOException Cannot locate resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518603/wpf-ioexception-cannot-locate-resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do, which has solved these types of one off things for me in the past, is create a new window in the folder its going to be in and start to copy the code over. Try copying just some of the code and functionality and build up to all of the code. If you finish copying over forget about ever having a problem and dismiss it as a one off. Its hard for us programmers to give up on figuring out why a problem occurs, but sometimes its better to just solve it the easy way and move on.

Comment: Problem is, that every new created window doesn't work ;[

Comment: OK, well that is at least new information that might lead us to figuring out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.

---

```
AfterLogin af = new AfterLogin();
af.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Make sure that AfterLogin.xaml file is there in your project. If it is not then import it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that AfterLogin.xaml file is there in your project. If it is not then import it.

If it is already there, then there must be one App.xaml file inyour project.

Open it! Inside `<Application>` tag,there will be `<Application.Resources>` tag, inside this tag make sure that code similar following exists.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="AfterLogin.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Are you able to replicate the same error when doing this in mainwindow' constructor itself? orelse this error was occurred in button click?